# What is the best way to temporarily set an enviornmental varabile?

Tags: command-line, scripts, environment-variables

I'm building a breathalyzer for my computer. If the breathalyzer fails, I want to set an environmental variable to make all instances of the web-browser to open in incognito mode.

Im debating whether I should try to set this up as a cronjob using the `at` command, but I'm wondering of there is a better way.

This is a novelty project for the lulz.

Comment: Environment variables that you set affect only your process and its child processes. Maybe a file in `/var/run`? You will have to modify the `firefox` script to pick a profile based on the file. You'll have to predefined incognito and normal Firefox profiles.